# wp_get_attachment_caption to pull Image Caption or alt

Tags: captions

```
$output .= '
    <img 
        class="class1" 
        src="'.$atts['to'].'" 
        alt="The First Caption" 
        width="100%" 
        height="auto"
    >';
```

Instead of first caption, I want to fetch the caption/description of the image.

can some one guide me how to do this?

I tried this → `wp_get_attachment_caption`
**but it didn't work.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly get an attachment's meta data if you have it's ID. The alt data for an attachment is stored in `_wp_attachment_image_alt`.

So, you can use:

```
$alt = get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
```

To get the caption of an image, you can use [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata).

```
$metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );
$caption = $metadata['image_meta']['caption'];
```

### EDIT

Based on the code in your comment, this is the full shortcode's code:

```
function simplisto_the_image($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array( 
            'to' => 'http://example.com/image.jpg' 
        ), 
        $atts
    );
    $caption = '';
    // Get the attachment's ID from its URL, if the URL is valid
    $url = filter_var( $atts['to'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    if( filter_var( $url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ) {
        $attachment_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $url );
        // Get the attachment's alt, if its a valid ID
        if( $attachment_id ){
            $caption = wp_get_attachment_caption( $attachment_id );
        }
    }

    $output = '<div class="lazyimg">'; 
    $output .= '<img class="lazyimg-popup" src="'.$atts['to'].'" alt="' .$caption. '" width="100%" height="auto">'; 
    $output .= '<i class="fa fa-expand" aria-hidden="true"></i>'; 
    $output .= '</div>'; 
    return $output; 
}
add_shortcode('simage', 'simplisto_the_image');
```

The shortcode will accept an image URL and fetch it's metadata, if it's valid.

Comment: sir, do we have the correct title or should we change this so that right people may find this in future?

Comment: Hi. The caption of an image is used for inline images, such as those description under the image in posts. But the alt attribute is used for search engines or when an image can not be loaded, so that the text is shown instead of the image. So, the correct way is to use alt for alt, and caption for description in posts.

Comment: Do you mean the title of the post? or your function? Since your question's title is correct.

Comment: Yes, I mean the post title.